# Laravel new example-app command doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I recently started working with Laravel framework. I keep installing it from cmd using this command ...
`composer global require laravel/installer`
and I follow the instruction through building a project by this command ...
`laravel new example-app`
but then it appears nothing except this ...
Crafting application...
and it doesn't build anything. It doesn't even show any error or an end up message and doesn't matter how much should I wait to complete the command.

but when I use this command ...
`composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app`
it creates project successfully.
I want to know why it can't build a project by the first command whereas both commands are suggested by Laravel documentation?

Answer (score -2):

The error message "Crafting application" in Laravel typically occurs when there's an issue with the Laravel installer or the command used to create a new Laravel application.

Verify Laravel Installer

```
composer global show laravel/installer
```

If the Laravel installer is not installed or you have an outdated version, you can install or update it using Composer:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Create a New Laravel Project

```
laravel new example-app
```

Check composer version.
Ensure that you have the latest version of Composer installed on your system. You can update Composer by running:

```
composer self-update
```

Verify PHP version:
Laravel requires PHP 7.3 or higher. Check your PHP version by running:

```
php -v
```

Or clear Composer cache:
sometimes, issues can be caused by cached files. Clear the Composer cache by running:

```
composer clear-cache
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: "_The error message "Crafting application"_" That doesn't look like an error message. "_Laravel requires PHP 7.3_" Laravel8, yes. Laravel 9 or 10 requires PHP 8.

Comment: i wrote "Laravel requires PHP 7.3 or higher". I am trying list some way to fix this issue @brombeer

Comment: I checked my php version and I found that it is 5.6.40 and I shocked because I installed the 8.2.8 by myself. Then I understand that it's because of wampserver. Now I don't know how to change it to a upper version. I mean cmd yet still accessing the 5.6.40 version.

Comment: @RamzNegar The version in your terminal and the version wamp is using may be different. You try it on https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fwfq.png or reinstall latest version wamp